# Python request prints 404 irrespective of the response

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, nginx

here is the code I am using to send the request:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost'
custom_request = "GET /_hidden/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: notlocalhost\r\n\r\n"
header={'Host': 'localhost','Content-Length': '56','User-Agent':'-' }
response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=header, data=custom_request)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

but I am getting only 404 responce like:

```html
404
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>404 - Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

but the server log shows the first request has an 302 and the second one has 200 OK

```
192.168.65.1 - - [01/Nov/2023:10:10:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "-" "-" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [01/Nov/2023:10:10:34 +0000] "GET /_hidden/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "-" "-"
```

I tried to capture the request and response using wireshark and the in the capture also it showed that the first response was an 302 redirect and the second one is an 200 OK response I have added the image for the reference ,
[image: wireshark capture]
My goal is to print both the response using python.